# Tool for comparing 2 binary files in Windows

Tags: binary, compare, filecompare

I need a tool to compare 2 binaries. The files are quite large. Some freeware or trial tools I found on the Internet are not convenient to use for large files. Can you recommend me some tools?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

A few possibilities:

- [VBinDiff](http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/) (binary diff, designed for large files)
- [WinDiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff)
- [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/)
- [HexCmp](http://www.fairdell.com/hexcmp/)

See also: https://web.archive.org/web/20151122151611/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688504/binary-diff-tool-for-very-large-files

Comment: I read in the notes of vBinDiff that "unlike diff, it works well with large files (up to 4 GB)."  So its suitability for working with large files depends on your definition of "large".  Also, I found it would mysteriously not start up under windows 7 x64.

Comment: Bare in mind that VBinDiff is a CLI program, so if you just try to run it on Windows, it will either appear not to start, or will very briefly show a command prompt window, which quickly disappears.  Open up a command prompt and run the program from there to see what arguments it accepts, and then use it from the command prompt accordingly.

Comment: vBinDiff works fine for me in Windows 7 x64.

Comment: When I tried using vBinDiff to compare two 1.4 GB files, it croaked. Neither can WinDiff handle such files.

Comment: @intuited I too found this quite humorous, although I found that it does work with files larger than 4 GB -- you just can't see diffs past 4 GB. That was enough for my purposes, although it would be great to have true LFS.

Comment: Anyone know were we can get WinDiff from?  The link is just to the wikipedia page.  There's a link to XPsp2 support tools there (which includes it), but that will only install on XP.

Comment: VBinDiff is AWESOME! Thought it is CLI, it is easy to use! Except maybe I had to search what RET key is xD It turns that it is the Enter key.

Comment: vBinDiff doesn't seem to deal with inserted bytes at all, so it's really not much better than HxD except that it shows you all the changes in red.

Comment: VBinDiff allows you to freeze one of the two scroll areas and when you make them sync again by scrolling the other one byte at a time it shows the same parts in white and diffs in red. So it is more of a manual tool, but with visual aid

Answer (score 257):

If you want to find out only whether or not the files are identical, you can use the Windows `fc` command in binary mode:

```
fc.exe /b file1 file2
```

For details, see [the reference for fc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc)

Comment: for the same purpose - only whether files are identical or not - a portable app Duplicate File Finder works good enough. Particularly for big files like .iso files.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, since this is windows native and not an addition 3rd party app

Comment: this just shows a list of bytecodes - there is also a "comp" tool in the command-line, but that one seems to require files to be of same size

Comment: This is exactly what I was lookig for, thanks a lot! This shows a table of the addresses which the changes and shows what changed.

Answer (score 27):

[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) also has a binary compare option:
go to: `File \\Compare by content`

ps. I guess some people may alredy be using this tool and may not be aware of the built-in feature.

Comment: This doesn't understand inserted content like a text diff tool, though, only changes to bytes.

Comment: @endolith and another thing to mention is that `Total Commander` costs $42 USD.

Answer (score 20):

My favorite "swiss knife" is Beyond Compare from http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: Beyond Compare doesn't work for binary files above 500MB...

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/Shelwien/cmp/

Comment: @BorisIvanov: It probably helps to mention that `Beyond Compare` is a paid software that will work only for 30 days. After that you'll have to get the license that costs $60.

Comment: strange things but version I have downloaded from official site always working even after trial period. no hacks.

Comment: Beyond Compare doesn't appear to have binary diffing capability, which is what the question was about.

Comment: Check Shelwien tool

Answer (score 16):

I prefer to use objcopy to convert to hex, then use diff.

Comment: Useful answer. The output file size is about 3 times as big as the input file.  This command will convert a binary file to hex. `objcopy -I binary -O ihex <in_file> <out_file>`

Answer (score 13):

In Cygwin:

`$cmp -bl <file1> <file2>`

diffs binary offsets and values are in decimal and octal respectively.. Vladi.