# Is there a tool to search differences in hex files?

Tags: file, hex

I have two hex files, and want to search for values that have changed from 9C in one file to 9D in the next one.

Even a tool that synchronizes the windows would work, as I can't seem to find any that enable me to do this. All I've found are tools that let me search for the same value and same address between two files.

Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you doing this on? That'll greatly dictate what programs will be suggested from simple 'grep' to 'Notepad++' and plugins

Comment: There's no such thing as a hex file. (All files are sequences of bytes.) But if you want look at the contents of a file visualised as a succession of bytes, displayed as as hex values, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166697/tool-for-comparing-2-binary-files-in-windows

Comment: Windows, I wish my desktop was Linux but I have too many programs required for school that can't simply run on Wine or the other. And yeah, just meant it more as a generalized term. Wrong context. I want to search for hex values, not through hex files!

Answer (score 0):

"There's no such thing as a hex file."
Oh well perhaps I should delete all my hex files.
I use Motorola and Intel formats of hex files (they are just text files representing bytes, but include a record structure for addresses, checksum etc per line. These files need to be treated as binary (in .gitattributes) since they cannot be merged.  I use Kdiff3 to see differences (or any other text diff tool).