# how to compare two exe files with x64dbg

Tags: exe, reverse-engineering, patch, ollydbg, x64dbg

I have two exe files a patched one and the original one (the original one was patched using x64dbg), I want to know what are the differences between the two files using x64dbg or ollydbg.Which mean I want to know where the original file was modified with x64dbg.
thanks.

Comment: Rather than a debugger/disassembler like `ollydbg` or `x64dbg`, you need a binary diffing tool such as `DarumGrim`, `bindiff`, `WinDiff`, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166697/tool-for-comparing-2-binary-files-in-windows for further information.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a debugger to do this, use a diff tool instead. These are some tools that can compare binary files:

- [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/): Freeware, close-source.
- [radare2-radiff2](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2): Freeware, open-source, [docs](https://radareorg.github.io/blog/posts/binary-diffing/)

These tools only compare the differences in bytes without disassembling them, but knowing the offsets of the differences you could easily take a look at the opcodes in x64dbg.

There is also an IDA plugin for this: [patchdiff2](https://github.com/filcab/patchdiff2), although I haven't tried this one. You can also consider writing your own x64dbg plugin, it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

i still couldn't find exact solution. lets assume that i patched File1.exe with x64dbg and saved, i want to compare file1.exe and patchedfile.exe by looking through jmp je mov dissasembled sections.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33459668)